# How to hide navbar in application template if the route is login

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have in my application template:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <!-- etc -->
</nav>
{{outlet}}
```

And in the login template, i don't want show the nav, so.. how exactly i could do this?? I searched but there isn't much resources.

The only solution i create is take off the nav and put in all templates, except for the login.. But i feel that i'm doing it wrong.. That Ember could help me achieve this using build in methods.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application controller:

```
hideNav: Ember.computed.equal('currentRouteName', 'login') // login is your route name
```

In application template:

```
{{#unless hideNav}}
  <nav class="navbar">
    <!-- etc -->
  </nav>
{{/unless}}
{{outlet}}
```